# Changing focus from UITextView to UITextField breaks constraints

Tags: ios, swift

When I click to change focus from a UITextView to a UITextField I get the following console output.  The UITextView must have focus first such that the keyboard is already displayed.

It only seems to occur when I test on an iPad with "Connect Hardware Keyboard" selected.  Is there anything I can do to remedy this?  Using Xcode 9.4.1.

```
2018-07-18 14:59:38.154928-0500 SingleViewTest[12870:502137] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is ...
2018-07-18 14:59:38.163269-0500 SingleViewTest[12870:502137] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2018-07-18 14:59:39.084531-0500 SingleViewTest[12870:502137] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60c000284ce0 h=--& v=--& UIKeyboardAssistantBar:0x7f9b6840e5c0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009e230 V:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b6840f240]   (active, names: '|':UIKeyboardAssistantBar:0x7f9b6840e5c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009e280 V:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b6840f240]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIKeyboardAssistantBar:0x7f9b6840e5c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000281900 'UIButtonBar.maximumAlignmentSize' _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f9b68644c70.height == UILayoutGuide:0x6080001b5540'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009d6f0 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x6080001b5540'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(9)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b6840f240 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009d650 'UIView-topMargin-guide-constraint' V:|-(10)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6080001b5540'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b6840f240 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009d6f0 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x6080001b5540'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(9)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b6840f240 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2018-07-18 14:59:39.085841-0500 SingleViewTest[12870:502137] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60c000284ce0 h=--& v=--& UIKeyboardAssistantBar:0x7f9b6840e5c0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009e2d0 V:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b6840fff0]   (active, names: '|':UIKeyboardAssistantBar:0x7f9b6840e5c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009e320 V:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b6840fff0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIKeyboardAssistantBar:0x7f9b6840e5c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000283660 'UIButtonBar.maximumAlignmentSize' UIView:0x7f9b684117d0.height == UILayoutGuide:0x6080001b58c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009da10 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x6080001b58c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(9)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b6840fff0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009d970 'UIView-topMargin-guide-constraint' V:|-(10)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6080001b58c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b6840fff0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009da10 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x6080001b58c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(9)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b6840fff0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2018-07-18 14:59:39.086724-0500 SingleViewTest[12870:502137] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60c000284ce0 h=--& v=--& UIKeyboardAssistantBar:0x7f9b6840e5c0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009e1e0 V:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b68410d80]   (active, names: '|':UIKeyboardAssistantBar:0x7f9b6840e5c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009e370 V:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b68410d80]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIKeyboardAssistantBar:0x7f9b6840e5c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000283f20 'UIButtonBar.maximumAlignmentSize' _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f9b6864e560.height == UILayoutGuide:0x6080001b5c40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009dd30 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x6080001b5c40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(9)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b68410d80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009dc90 'UIView-topMargin-guide-constraint' V:|-(10)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6080001b5c40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b68410d80 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009dd30 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x6080001b5c40'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(9)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x7f9b68410d80 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Edit:  A similar message appears when a UITextView loses focus after clicking a button.

Edit: [storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysDjG.png)

Comment: Please share also the xib or the view in the storyboard

Comment: Storyboard image attached.  It's as basic as can be.